# collect heap dump in java 1.4.0 in windows

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am trying to collect heap dump for my application. It's running a java 1.4.0 on Windows platform. The option like -xxheapdump options won't work. Do v have any tool to achieve this. 
Highly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it like this? -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak

maybe this link is of use to you: http://www.startux.de/index.php/component/content/article/25-java/45-java-heap-dump

This link is also interesting:

http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/heap_dumps_are_back_with